# How to get wave module methods for reading a .wav audio but with a temporary file tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile obtained from fastAPI post request?

Tags: python, fastapi, wave

I have a function that receives a .wav audio path directory and return its pcm_data in bytes, sample_rate as int and duration as float.

```
def read_wave(self, path: str) -> Dict:
   with contextlib.closing(wave.open(path, "rb")) as wf:

     num_channels: int = wf.getnchannels()
     assert num_channels == 1
     sample_width: int = wf.getsampwidth()
     assert sample_width == 2
     sample_rate: int = wf.getframerate()
     assert sample_rate in (8000, 16000, 32000)
     frames: int = wf.getnframes()
     pcm_data: bytes = wf.readframes(frames)
     duration: float = frames / sample_rate

     return {
          "pcm_data": pcm_data,
          "sample_rate": sample_rate,
          "duration": duration,
     }
```

Now I want that the audio file comes from a uploaded audio using POST request with FastAPI, so if I upload a .wav audio using the UploadFile class from fastapi, I get a tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile, how can I adapt the first function for this case.

```
@app.post(path="/upload-audios/")
async def upload_audios(audios: list[UploadFile] = File(...)):
   pass
```

Comment: The `wave.open` method supports a file like object, so you should be able to use the `.file` attribute directly with `wave.open` (it exposes the SpooledTemporaryFile instance directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wave.open` function supports a file like object, so you can use the  `.file` attribute of `UploadFile` directly (it represents the SpooledTemporaryFile instance).